# Add data from dataframe to filepath

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) containing filenames. I want to iterate over the filenames in df and import them to analyze them one by one as in the example below:

```
df=[file_1.mpf, file_2.mpf, file_3.mpf....file_n.mpf]

for i in range(len(df)

    file_path = r'C:Users\myfolder\df[i]'

    open(file_path, 'r') as file
```

Does this make any sense?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Holmbrero

Comment: i think you need to open them in different names, like that you would only get the last one as 'file', cause in every iteration the for-loop 'file' is overwritten.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to [read the question asking guide to get better answers faster](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Iterating over rows is generally done with `df.iterrows()` or `df.itertuples()`[More info here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) Additionally, are you sure you're actually handling a Pandas DataFrame? The sample data you've provided is a list. Otherwise, please provide sample data so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Floriancitt! I did not know about either df.iterrows nor df.itertuples. I'll have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its actually in a pandas dataframe, you would have to do something like this to get the filenames from the dataframe

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    file_path = "C:/Users/myfolder/" + row["filename"]
    open(file_path, 'r') as file
```

The code you have assumes its a list not a pandas df

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. It is in a Pandas dataframe which I initiated earlier in the code. Thanks for your answer. What am I supposed to change filename to? Is it index?

Regards,
Holmbrero

Comment: @Holmbrero you would only need to change `filename` in `row['filename']` to what your column is labeled